# Using arearange series in highchart on inverted graphs

Tags: highcharts

my question is quite simple : 
have you already experienced some trouble using the `arearange` series on `inverted` chart with Hightchart ?

As you can see in this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ693/1/) ( its the arearange example where I've added the inverted settings.)

```
        chart: {
            type: 'arearange',
            zoomType: 'x',
            inverted:true //toggle this setting true/ false to see the differences
        },
```

The displayed data seems totally broken. We can zoom in to compare, the displayed data is totally different when inverted :/

Anybody aware of this ?
do you know a workaround so we can use both  `inverted` and `arearange` in the same chart ?
Or simply I'm using this the wrong way ?

Comment: Looks like the data has been flipped.  Does this like right: http://jsfiddle.net/YJ693/2/

Comment: no, not at all. You can see the original graph here : http://jsfiddle.net/YJ693/  And also we can see the correct values displayed in the tooltip which are very diferent from what the graph is showing.

Comment: here is a simpler example, if it can help to see what's happenning : http://jsfiddle.net/2me4Z/13/

Comment: Added a new issue to the highchart github : https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed now, see https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1930. It was a regression, worked in 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little workaround, since the corrupted values seemed flipped, I've played with my computed values for the second data series of the `arearange`.

I was applying a linear transformation to map the values of the second series on the first series's axis. The result [is good on normal chart](http://jsfiddle.net/2me4Z/11/) but seemed [flipped on inverted charts](http://jsfiddle.net/2me4Z/12/)

What I'm doing to fix the result on the inverted version is changing the linear tranformation from this :

```
var value2 = a*data2[index] + b;
```

to this :

```
var value2 = max1-(a*data2[index]);
```

where **max1** if the max value for the first series axis. So I guess the inverted chart apply a wrong transformation on the second series of the arearange such as :

```
 val = axisMax - val;
```

or something similar.

I'm still looking for a complete fix.