# How to manage event through a fill color with highchart?

Tags: svg, highcharts, dom-events

I've got two series in an Highchart graph. Both are handling event like **mousemove** (to show tooltip) and mouse **click**.

Unfortunatly one of those series is an `area` serie which block any event to be triggered by the other one.

Let's say I've got those series with those plot options :

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    color:'red',
    data: [29.9, 51.5, 16.4, 19.2, 44.0, 16.0, 35.6, 48.5, 26.4, 4.1, 9.6, 54.4]        
},
{
    type:'area',
    data: [39.9, 75.5, 120.4, 150.2, 130.0, 120.0, 140.6, 158.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}
]
}
```

as seen in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8qYK/)

I can never click or see the tooltip on the red series points.

What I could do is to change the order of the series so the red one is over the blue one.
( [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/j8qYK/1/)). But I've got situations where I've got several area graphs over each other [like that](http://jsfiddle.net/j8qYK/2/). In this case, change the order won't help.
Is there a way I can handle events through the fill area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a way that suit my need :  manimulating SVG element order as indicated in this topic : 
[SVG re-ordering z-index (Raphael optional)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566406/svg-re-ordering-z-index-raphael-optional)

I'm using this code in the redraw event of the chart :

```
redraw : function(){
    //get a reference on the first series svg element.
    var svgSeriesParent = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-series')[0];

    //loop on all the path drawn by highchart
    var pathArray = document.querySelectorAll('path');

    for (var pathIndex = 0; pathIndex < pathArray.length; pathIndex++) {
        var pathObj = pathArray[pathIndex];
        //if attribute fill is not "none", this is an area path.
        if ($(pathObj).attr('fill') !== "none") {

            //move the current fill path before the first series svg element.
            svgSeriesParent.insertBefore(pathObj, svgSeriesParent.firstChild);
        }
    }
}
```

See the result in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8qYK/5/)

**Limitation :**
The fill area doesn't have the same svg group anymore thus, hidding / showing the series is broken : all the fill area are considered being part of the first series. (click in the legend to see it).

In my case I don't need to hide series so I'll go on with this solution.

The svg order manipulation is not complicated that's why I would expect highchart to manage this case :  add a `fillZIndex` parametter doesn't seem difficult and could be pretty usefull...

Answer (score 0):

Only what comes to my mind is using 4 series, 2 area and 2 lines and use `index`.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8qYK/3/

Comment: Well  ok, now let's say I've got 20 graphs with 4000 points each...  and need to be running on mobile devices. Do I really want to add one more data series for each area graph I've got ? More over I've already done that in some other case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855265/how-to-fill-the-area-between-two-series-with-multiples-yaxis-in-highchart.   Pretty heavy  no ?