# How to fill area between two serieses in Hightcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to fill the area between two serieses (when serieses cross each other). See below. I tried the 'arearange' chart type but it filled most of the chart with solid colors. I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855265/how-to-fill-the-area-between-two-series-with-multiples-yaxis-in-highchart) but I wanted to know if Highcharts supports what I want or I have to use the solution posted in that question.

**Chart now:**
[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

**type:'arearange'**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use three series, first / second as lines, third as arearange with defined values.

Related topic: [How to fill the Area between two series with multiples yAxis in HighChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855265/how-to-fill-the-area-between-two-series-with-multiples-yaxis-in-highchart/16981315#16981315)