# Highcharts:Remove the color area below the 2 series

Tags: highcharts

I want fill color in between the 2 series.I tried setting the white color for the second series but the transparent first series color is visible.

```
 yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Billions'
    },

},
tooltip: {
    split: true,
},
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        lineColor: '#666666',
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#666666'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Asia',
    data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268],
    color: '#A5E1D2',
    lineColor: '#008484',
    lineWidth: 2,
}, {
    name: 'Africa',
    data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766],
    color: 'white',
    lineColor: '#002E2E',
    lineWidth: 2,

}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diasraphael88/tz3ecg21/27/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855265/how-to-fill-the-area-between-two-series-with-multiples-yaxis-in-highchart)

This is the updated jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/diasraphael88/hdg83Lpw/

```
{
    color: '#A5E1D2',
    data: [3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3]
},{
    color: '#A5E1D2',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
},{
    id: 'transparent',
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    data: [27,25,16,13,9,17,11]
}]
}, function(chart){
chart.get('transparent').area.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linearGradient for the color of the first series and set the color to 'transparent' for the second series

```
series: [{
        name: 'Asia',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268],
        color: {
    linearGradient: { x1: 0.02, x2: 0.98, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
    stops: [
        [0, 'green'],
        [0.8, 'transparent'],
    ]
},
        lineColor: '#008484',
        lineWidth: 2,
    }, {
        name: 'Africa',
        data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766],
        color: 'transparent',
        lineColor: '#002E2E',
        lineWidth: 2,

    }]
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3k5t0r4v/

Here you can read more about how linearGradient works and other methods to style your highcharts:

[Colors in Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors)

Comment: I want the chart to be exactly like this jsfiddle.but the problem here is the values are getting stacked on top of the other. Do you have any solution to overcome this problem.